Show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{3n^4 - 5n^3 - 9n^2 + n -3}{n^4 -3n^3}$ converges using epsilon delta definition of convergence
Its is obvious that the given sequence converges to 3 but the problem is how do i show this using the epsilon delta definition. I have two approaches but i get stuck in both of them midway.
Approach One
We need to find a number $N \in \mathbb{N}\;\text{such that for }$ $\epsilon > 0$ 
Now, generally in these situations we start from $$ |a_n -3|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |\frac{3n^4 - 5n^3 - 9n^2 + n -3}{n^4 -3n^3} -3 |<\epsilon$$ and then simply the above inequality to get $n > f(\epsilon)$ and we shall be done. However after getting to this,
\begin{equation}
|\frac{4n^3-9n^2+n-3}{n^4-3n^3}|<\epsilon \tag{1}
\end{equation}
I get stuck...how do I isolate $n$?
Approach Two
Another approach that I know of is to find a function (of $n$) which is greater than (1) and a simpler function of $n$ and then back track to choose a value of $N$ so that $(1)$ holds.
In this i have got $\dots$
$$
\text{We need to show that}\\
\forall\, \epsilon >0 ,\, \exists\, N>0\, \text{such that}\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N},\, n>N\Rightarrow |a_n-3|<\epsilon \\
\text{Let $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ = _____ > 0},\\
\text{Suppose,$n>N$}\\
|a_n -3| =  |\frac{3n^4 - 5n^3 - 9n^2 + n -3}{n^4 -3n^3} -3 |\\
= |\frac{4n^3-9n^2+n-3}{n^4-3n^3}| < f(n)\\ \text{[From what i know, we need to maximise the numerator and minimize}\\
\text{the denomination to get the function f ]}\\
\text{I can came up with the following}\\
f(n) = |\frac{6n^3}{\text{Dont know what to put here}}|\\
$$
And this is where I am stuck
Thank you.

Yes, this is something that i thought of doing but i fail to see how this would help me  find the N...could you please elaborate a bit further.
Thank you.

As a hint: if $n \ge 6$, then $n^4 - 3n^3 \ge \frac{1}{2} n^4$.  On the other hand, $|4n^3 - 9n^2 + n - 3| \le (4 + 9 + 1 + 3) n^3$.  So, $\left| \frac{4n^3 - 9n^2 + n - 3}{n^4 - 3n^3} \right|\le \frac{34}{n}$.

@DanielSchepler Thank you for your hint but I still hit a snag. Going by your hint, $\frac{17}{2n} < \frac{17}{2N}$ which gives the desired value for N to be = $\frac{17}{2\epsilon}$. Now this should should for all epsilons, but if i pick my epsilon such that my N is < 6 then  $n^4-3n^3 \ge \frac{1}{2}n^4$ wont hold. How Should work around this?

So, you want to ensure both that $n \ge 6$ and that $n \ge \frac{34}{\varepsilon}$.  The standard way to ensure that is to set $N := \max(6, 34/\varepsilon)$.
